# Creacion de array en javascript

Tags: javascript, angular

Buen día a todos, tengo dos objetos, usuarioy pagosUsuario los uno para que se conviertan en uno solo asi en una función:

```
datosJuntos = {...usuario, ...pagosUsuario};
```

Luego los meto a un array utilizando un ciclo para llenarlo con varios objetos:

```
datosUsuario.push( datosJuntos ) ;
```

y esto lo retorno en la funcion:

```
return datosUsuario;
```

Lo anterior funciona, el problema es que no me regresa el array como lo necesito para poder llenar una tabla en angular y no entiendo por que, esto se explica mucho mejor en la imagen el cuadro verde es como lo requiero pero como me llega es como el cuadro rojo :( y no se como regresarlo de esa forma ¿alguien podría compadecerse? :)

El codigo de mi funcion que retorna el array que necesito es:

```
async getUsersConMesesPagados(){
  const userRef = this.afs.firestore.collection('users');
  const pagosRef = this.afs.firestore.collection('pagos/2020/pagosResumen');

  let datosUsuario = [];
  let pagosUsuario;

  const users = await userRef.get().then( usuarios => {
    // console.log('data en GetUsers: ', dusuariosata);
    usuarios.forEach( async user => {
      let usuario = user.data();
      let pagos = await pagosRef.doc(user.id).collection('pagos').get();
      pagos.forEach( pagos => {
        // Pagos por usuario console.log('pagos', pagos.data());
        pagosUsuario = pagos.data();
      });

      let datosJuntos = [];
      datosJuntos = {...usuario, ...pagosUsuario};
      datosUsuario.push( datosJuntos ) ;
    });
  });
  // console.log('datos usuarios:', datosUsuario);
  return datosUsuario;
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agrega tu código del array para poder reproducir tu escenario

Comment: Agrega donde creas los objetos, creo que es relevante y fundamental para que obtengas una respuesta.

Comment: gracias por sus comentarios, he editado la pregunta para poner el codigo de la funcion completa, saludos!

Answer (score 1):

Lo que ocurre es que `push` inserta `datosJuntos` como **un elemento** en el array `datosUsuario`; no interpreta como hacer un ciclo para poblarlo; dependiendo que desees hacer, si tu intención es solo igualar ambos array prueba con lo siguiente:

```
datosUsuario= datosJuntos.slice();
```

Adicionalmente de comento de [Lodash](https://lodash.com/) que tiene muchas cosas para el manejo de array; por ejemplo con esta puedes usar [`union`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#union); lo que te permitira unir varios array; a manera de ejemplo para lo que quieres sería:

```
datosUsuario= _.union(datosUsuario, datosJuntos);
```

Recuerda siempre inicializar las variables antes de su uso; así mismo si `datosUsuario`esta vacía `datosJuntos` sería el resultado final; si `datosUsuario` a estos se le agregarian los de`datosJuntos`.

Si estas usando AngularJS la libreria **lodash** tendrá el mismo alias que es el guión bajo que en el ejemplo proporciono; si no, recuerda el alias que tendrá será el que tu asignes en el `import`.

Comment: agradezco tu comentario pero la verdad creo que no entendi :( y por ejemplo esto marca un error: datosUsuario= datosJuntos.slice();  seguire buscando porque si esta raro :(